# mysql combining different count() on same table

Tags: mysql

My database holds a 'lastOnline' timestamp variable that get updates when a user logs in. I want to use this to retrive 3 values

```
[The total amount of users][users online today][users online in the last hour].
```

I can do each statement seperately

```
SELECT count(u.id) AS usersTotal FROM user u

SELECT count(u.id) AS usersDay FROM user u
WHERE u.lastOnline >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

SELECT count(u.id) AS usersHour FROM user u
WHERE u.lastOnline >= now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

but I am having trouble joining/union the 3 of them into one query

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT count(u.id) AS usersTotal 
      ,SUM(u.lastOnline >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)  AS usersDay
      ,SUM(u.lastOnline >= now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AS usersHour
FROM user u;
```

How it works:

`u.lastOnline >= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` return true(1) or false(0).

Comment: Perfect... Thanks alot!